# Compute standard deviation from a column of collection

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following dataframe and need to compute the standard deviation of each vector in the column salary.

| dept_name | salary |
| --- | --- |
| Sales | [30, 36] |
| Finance | [10, 98] |
| Marketing | [20, 22] |
| IT | [40, 90] |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1 - using UDF

1. Create a function to calculate the standard deviation for a python list.
2. Assign that function to a pyspark sql `udf`.
3. Create a new `stdev_salary` column that applies the `udf` to the `salary` column using `withColumn`.

```
# imports required for this solution
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

# calculate std dev for list input
def stdev_list(salary_list):
    mean = sum(salary_list) / len(salary_list)
    variance = sum([((x - mean) ** 2) for x in salary_list]) / len(salary_list)
    stdev = variance ** 0.5
    return stdev

# apply std dev function to pyspark sql udf
stdev_udf = udf(stdev_list, FloatType() )

# make a new column using the pyspark sql udf
df = df.withColumn('stdev_salary',stdev_udf('salary'))
```

More about the pyspark sql `udf` function here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html

#### Option 2 - not using UDF

1. First `explode` the `salary` column so each salary item is represented on a new row

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df_exploded = df.select('dept_name', 'salary', F.explode('salary').alias('salary_item'))
```

2. Then, calculate the standard deviation using the `salary_item` column while grouping by `dept_name` and `salary`

```
df_final = df_exploded.groupBy('dept_name', 'salary').agg(F.stddev('salary_item').alias('stddev_salary'))
```

Comment: I wanted not to use UDF but I think it's the only possibility I get. Thanks

Comment: Can we explode the column first and use the `stddev`?

Comment: Yep that should be an option, I'll update the solution to include that option as well